# Jquery toggle() not working?

Tags: jquery

I have this code but the function is not working. Why?

```
function show_slider().toggle
{          
    $(".theme-liquid .mobile-slider").css({
      left:"auto"
    });

    $("#mobile-nav-body").css({
      width:"100%",  
      overflow:"hidden",  
    });

    $("#mobile-nav-body").animate({
      "margin-left":250, 
    },slider_speed);   
}
```

Comment: you should put brackets around that code

Comment: what is `<pre>` for ? also provide jsFiddle

Comment: <pre> was added by user NullReferenceException, I don't know why ;]

Comment: I really don't know where to start with this one, there is so much wrong!

Comment: I'm wondering what you expect to do toggle here???

Comment: add `/*` at the start just before `function` and `*/` at the end after the final `}` ... Fixed?! :)

Comment: How can making a question easy to understand be so hard?
Please provide information on what exactly fails to work and how and when you attempt to call the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
show_slider().toggle
```

Not a valid function name. If show_slider is an object you mean:

```
show_slider.toggle = function(){
```

Or you might have meant show_slider to be the function name, and the toggle is erronious:

```
function show_slider(){
```

Even after you fix that you still have:

```
overflow:"hidden",
```

Extra comma, with nothing following. It should be removed.

```
"margin-left":250
```

Dashes cannot be in the key. You should, though it may not necessary, specify the unit. I imagine you mean:

```
"marginLeft":"250px"
```

You also don't show where slider_speed is defined, make sure it is really in scope here.

Comment: jQuery does work without units. It then interprets the number as pixels. What doesn't work is using dashes in the object keys. The correct notation is `marginLeft: 250`.